# Heroku App Crashed After pushing and releasing by gitlab-ci

Tags: django, docker, heroku, gitlab-ci

I have deployed a Django application on Heroku server. I have pushed my project without migrations and database manually by Heroku CLI. Then, pushing by Gitlab ci (which does the migrations before push) gives me app crashed error on Heroku side. I have encountered many "app crashed" errors before and could solve them by inspecting the logs. But this time I cannot understand what is the issue. 
I am sure that files are completely pushed and the application is released.

**Here is my Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath Code Code.wsgi --log-file -
```

My project is in the "Code" folder and my Django project name is Code.

**Error part of the heroku logs**:

```
2019-06-08T08:02:50.549319+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (c1f5c903bedb) by user arminbehnamnia@gmail.com
2019-06-08T08:02:50.549319+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user arminbehnamnia@gmail.com
2019-06-08T08:02:51.268875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-06-08T08:02:51.277247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-06-08T08:02:52.494158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-06-08T08:02:52.517991+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-08 08:02:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-06-08T08:02:52.519983+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-08 08:02:52 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-06-08T08:02:52.529529+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-08 08:02:52 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-06-08T08:02:52.823141+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-08 08:02:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-06-08T08:02:52.958760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-06-08T08:03:09.777009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2019-06-08T08:03:11.647048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-06-08T08:03:11.654524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-06-08T08:03:11.625687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
.
.
.
2019-06-08T08:17:16.898569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=makan-system.herokuapp.com request_id=de4fbb8e-cd14-4263-bb6f-a8d0f956a519 fwd="69.55.54.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**My .gitlab-ci.yml file**:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - push
tests:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker login -u armin_gm -p $PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com
  script:
    - docker build . -t test_django
    - docker ps
    - docker run --name=testDjango test_django python /makanapp/Code/manage.py test registration
  when: on_success
build:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u armin_gm -p $PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/armin_gm/asd_project_98_6 .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/armin_gm/asd_project_98_6
push_to_heroku:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: push
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
    # This is for gitlab
    - docker login -u armin_gm -p $PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com
    #- docker pull  registry.gitlab.com/armin_gm/asd_project_98_6:latest
    - docker build . -t push_to_django
    - docker ps
    # This is for heroku
    - docker login --username=arminbehnamnia@gmail.com  --password=$AUTH_TOKEN registry.heroku.com
    - docker tag push_to_django:latest registry.heroku.com/makan-system/web:latest
    - docker push registry.heroku.com/makan-system/web:latest
    - docker run --rm -e HEROKU_API_KEY=$AUTH_TOKEN wingrunr21/alpine-heroku-cli container:release web --app makan-system
```

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# Official Python image
FROM python:latest
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# create root directory for project, set the working directory and move all files
RUN mkdir /makanapp
WORKDIR /makanapp
ADD . /makanapp/
# Web server will listen to this port
EXPOSE 8000
# Install all libraries we saved to requirements.txt file
#RUN apt-get -y update
#RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev python3-setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python ./Code/manage.py makemigrations
RUN python ./Code/manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: could you also add your gitlab-ci configuration yaml file?

Comment: I added the file.